# Looking for Suggestions on Photo Galleries

Tags: mobile, clone, lightbox

I am running a website for my local Little League and the website was just redone to be responsive so that's out of the way. We have a page that is dedicated to pictures and events during the year and we have about 15 different galleries. All of the photos are different sizes. We've used Lightbox in the past but from what I am reading there isn't a way to get it working on mobile devices. Is there anything that's out there that doesn't need much javascript or jquery knowledge to use? I've looked and tried things but they either don't work or only work with one gallery.

I thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use fancybox latest version and it's amazing and easy to use.